# Regex to match SUBSTR function with trailing IN clause

Tags: php, regex

I'm using PHP `preg_match_all()` to find `SUBSTR()` function calls in WHERE clauses in SQL queries. The match shall return both the function call including parameters and also the comparison operator and compared value. Example:

```
SUBSTR(d.chassinummer, 7, 2) = 'CD'
```

In query strings the result from `SUBSTR()` is compared either using equal operator or `IN()` operator. There are often multiple and mixed combinations of the two in any query. An example query can look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE col_a = 'abc' 
AND SUBSTR(col_b, 7, 2) = 'cd' 
AND col_c LIKE 'ACD0%' 
AND SUBSTR(col_d, 10, 1) IN ('A','B','C') 
AND SUBSTR(col_e, 5, 3) = 'cde' 
AND SUBSTR(col_f, 2, 1) IN ('C','D','E')
```

*Note: There are no line breaks in the query strings that I match on.*

I managed to write a pattern that almost catches the cases where equals operator is used. It looks like this

```
preg_match_all('/substr\(.*?\) *?= *?\'.*?\'/i', $query, $matches);
```

However in the given example query my pattern fails by terminating a match where `IN()` is present on a later match. After fiddling with this for a while I surrender and turn to the experts for some support. Can anyone help me understand how to extract the following matches from the given example query

1. `SUBSTR(col_b, 7, 2) = 'cd'`
2. `SUBSTR(col_d, 10, 1) IN ('A','B','C')`
3. `SUBSTR(col_e, 5, 3) = 'cde'`
4. `SUBSTR(col_f, 2, 1) IN ('C','D','E')`

If it is easier to divide it into two separate patterns and use two `preg_match_all()` calls, that is fine by me, however if it can be done in one call that would feel cleaner.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: For the examples, you might try it like `substr\([^()]*\)\h*(?:=\h*'[^']*'|IN\h*\([^()]*\))` https://regex101.com/r/zv5b9C/1 but it will not take nesting queries into account.

Comment: Try this regex `/substr\(.*?\)*?(:?\=|IN)*?(:?\'|\().*(:?\'|\))/gi`  https://regex101.com/r/y9f52A/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example data (not taking nested queries into account) you might use:

```
substr\([^()]*\)\h*(?:=\h*'[^']*'|IN\h*\([^()]*\))
```

The pattern matches:

- `substr\([^()]*\)`
- `\h*` Match optional spaces
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `=\h*'[^']*'` match `=` then optional spaces and from `'` till `'` not matching `'` in between
  - `|` Or
  - `IN\h*\([^()]*\)` Match `IN` then optional spaces and from `(` till `)` not matching `(` and `)` in between
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zv5b9C/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/7cqHm)

Example

```
$re = '`substr\([^()]*\)\h*(?:=\h*\'[^\']*\'|IN\h*\([^()]*\))`mi';
$str = <<<STR
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE col_a = 'abc' 
AND SUBSTR(col_b, 7, 2) = 'cd' 
AND col_c LIKE 'ACD0%' 
AND SUBSTR(col_d, 10, 1) IN ('A','B','C') 
AND SUBSTR(col_e, 5, 3) = 'cde' 
AND SUBSTR(col_f, 2, 1) IN ('C','D','E')
STR;

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, 0);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => SUBSTR(col_b, 7, 2) = 'cd'
    [1] => SUBSTR(col_d, 10, 1) IN ('A','B','C')
    [2] => SUBSTR(col_e, 5, 3) = 'cde'
    [3] => SUBSTR(col_f, 2, 1) IN ('C','D','E')
)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Seems to work well for my collection of queries. A well written answer, awesome! I will dissect it and learn =D